# when i update one row in mysql all other rows are getting updated with the same data

Tags: php, mysql

I seem to have a problem with updating data in mysql where if i update one row all rows get updated or some rows after that row get updated with the same data as the updated one. 
My query :

```
$qry="UPDATE stud_proj
      set 
      title='$projtit',
      yop='$yop',
      proj_defn='$projdef',
      proj_desc='$desc',
      learning='$learn',
      attachments='$file_name',
      link='$dlink',
      tags='$tags',
      categ_id='$cid'
      where proj_id=$pid";
```

I get the project id from an ajax call on a form and get the category id from  a select statement

```
$res2=mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * from categ where proj_categ='$pcatg'");
```

Comment: Maybe you are SQL injecting yourself and the `where` doesn't execute? What's the compiled query look like? `where proj_id=$pid` looks like it'd limit it to one row, is `proj_id` unique?

Comment: Maybe all of the rows have the same `proj_id` value?  Maybe the query you're executing isn't what you think it is?  What is the actual query at runtime and what does the data look like?

Comment: Yes, proj_id is unique. The data gets updated normally most of the times but sometimes this problem occurs

Comment: proj_id is unique for every row.. even when all rows get updated with same data the proj_id remains unique

Comment: Output `$qry` on an instance where the data gets updated incorrectly. It will be hard for us to help without a reproducible example.

Comment: Share complete code and type of column `proj_id` ?

Comment: @she_be_me: `"sometimes this problem occurs"` - Your code is wide open to SQL injection, so "sometimes" you don't even know what query you're executing.  Correct that problem and this one will likely become moot.

Comment: *Always* use parameters rather than stuffing values into the query string.  You don't know what the strings contain, and a string containing `';` could result in a very different query.

Comment: Maybe it is happening coz of sql injections like @David said, I'll check for those and get back. Thank u so much for all your responses!

Comment: You can quickly fix that by parameterizing. See http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php.